# Basic dialect, what language is this?

Tags: basic

I'm using Concerto post processing app from AVL and I'm having hard time with scripting language we use here. It looks like MS visual basic but not that much and I want to know more about what version of Basic is this, so that I can find more documentation on the web.

---

When I try code from MS Visual Basic documentation site, like generating int array and puting some elements to initialize it (as you can see below), I got syntax error on Concerto Scripting editor

```
' Declare a single-dimension array and set its 4 values.
Dim numbers = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8}
```

---

This is from Concerto's own documentation and I cannot find how to create a simple array but Dataset istead, which is something similar I beleive

### NewDSArray

This function generates a new array.

#### Syntax:

A = NewDSArray([Rows], [Columns])

#### Parameters:

- Rows (optional, 1 = default): Numeric initial number of lines
- Columns (optional, 0 = default): Numeric initial number of columns

#### Function:

A is now a new array with which the Dataset Array class commands can be used.

```
thisDSMatrix=newdsarray(1,2)
FirstCol={1,2,3}
FirstCol.name="FirstCol" //.name will pass the name into the matrix
thisDSMatrix.PutCell(FirstCol,1,1)
SecondCol={4,5,6}
SecondCol.name="SecondCol"
thisDSMatrix.PutCell(SecondCol,1,2)
Mcols=thisDSMatrix.ColCount //returns 2
Mrows=thisDSMatrix.RowCount //returns 1
thisDSMatrix.AddColumn("MyNewCol") //a column is added and thisDSMatrix.ColCount will now show 3
thisDSMatrix.PutCell({7,8,9},1,thisDSMatrix.ColCount)
return thisDSMatrix
```

I appreciate if you can help me to spot exact version of Basic Concerto uses. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you certain that this is not a Concerto-proprietary language (even if based on BASIC)? I would absolutely consult Concerto's documentation for more information.

Comment: Except for the comments started with // this looks like Microsoft Visual Basic .Net. But comments are not starting with a double slash in that language.

Answer (score 1):

We had basically the same issue and because I didn't want to learn a proprietary language I dicided to go with Python. AVL Concerto provides from version V5.x onwards a Python-API. Despite that the API is not perfect from my point of view, this might be an alternative to the Concerto scripting language. And learning Python will thertenly the better solution.